# How do I skip ahead and out of quotes in NetBeans 7.2 IDE?

Tags: html, netbeans

I have a very simple question: how do I skip out and ahead of automatically-inserted quotes when I am finished typing in NetBeans 7.2 IDE? For example, when I am finished typing what i want to go in the quotes and my cursor is here (cursor represented by the pipe):

```
    <div class="foo|"
```

how do I skip out and ahead of the quotes without having to stretch my pinky to the end key or right arrow key?

As silly as this may sound, please allow me to express my sincerity behind this question. It is slowing my typing speed down considerably and causing a constant distraction. I know in Eclipse this is done with the tab key, but this does not work in NetBeans. I have spent probably about a cumulative of an hour looking for an answer to this pretty basic question, and now I turn to SO.

Thanks to everyone on SO :-)

Comment: Not sure whether there's a better way but hitting the **End** key is a sort of workaround (unless you're editing an existing line).

Comment: Yes that is what I am currently doing. As a matter of ergonomics and typing speed, however, reaching for the end key every time I assign a value to a html attribute is cumbersome and slow (as opposed to, say, hitting the tab key). It is a significant productivity bottleneck for me lol!

Comment: you could just type the second quote - netbeans will work out what you mean and jump you past the quote it's inserted. If you're typing naturally, it's probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: ps - you know netbeans 7.3 is out now? it's not a huge update, but there are some nice new features that make it worth upgrading.

Comment: @Spudley Ah perfect! It's the simple things . . . And, yes I am downloading 7.3 as we speak. I noticed 7.3 has some new functionality for JavaScript editing. If you change your comment to an answer I will accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just type the second quote - netbeans will work out what you mean and jump you past the quote it's inserted. If you're typing naturally, it's probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Sometimes when I try this it just adds another set of quotes. Very annoying. I have been using the right arrow key to move past the closing quote which breaks my flow.